# extending namespace std via partial template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer, explicit-specialization

As far as I know, we are allowed (with some exceptions that I won't mention here) to "extend" `namespace std` by totally specializing a `std` template function such as `std::swap`, i.e.

```
namespace std
{
    template<>
    void swap<Foo>(Foo& lhs, Foo& rhs){...}
}
```

is perfectly valid.

Since C++11, we can now partially specialize functions. I believe that we can then play the same game and extend `std` via partial specialization, like

```
namespace std
{
    template<typename T>
    void swap<Foo<T>>(Foo<T>& lhs, Foo<T>& rhs){...}
}
```

however I am not sure about this and couldn't find the proper explaining section in the standard. Is the code immediately above correct or does it lead to UB?

PS: As @Columbo mentioned in the answer, we cannot partially specialize function templates, not even in C++11/14. For some reason I thought one can do that, I believed it was at least a proposal.

Comment: Ermm, what!? You can't partially specialize function templates, not even in C++14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might mean [namespace.std]/1:

> A program may add a template specialization for any standard library
> template to namespace `std` **only if the declaration depends on a
> user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library
> requirements for the original template and is not explicitly
> prohibited<sup>181</sup>.**
>
> ---
>
> <sup>181)</sup> Any library code that instantiates other library templates must be prepared to work adequately with any user-supplied
> specialization that meets the minimum requirements of the Standard.

If partial specializations of function templates are ever introduced, this quote would also implicitly cover them (as it doesn't restrict itself on explicit specialization).

Comment: Yes, indeed. Why did I have the feeling that we can partially specialize function templates?! Indeed the code above doesn't even compile, should have checked before asking ;)

Comment: @vsoftco Because the only thing that prevents it is the standard :)